# Switch on rebuild for Commerce Cores

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, indexing, cloud

I am using two Solr Cloud Instance with two Zookeeper and indexed Commerce Indexes (CustomersScope, OrdersScope, CatalogItemsScope) in it. And now I want to apply Switch On Rebuild for that collections. But after making some changes in the wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Search.PolicySet-1.0.0.json as :

```
 "$type":  "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.SearchScopePolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search",
 "Name": "CatalogItemsScope",
 "CurrentIndexName":"CatalogItemsScope",
 "SwitchOnRebuild": true,
 "SwitchOnRebuildReset": false,
 "SwitchOnRebuildClearPreviousIndex": true,
 "SwitchOnRebuildPrimaryIndexName":"CatalogItemsScope",
 "SwitchOnRebuildSecondaryIndexName":"CatalogItemsScope-Rebuild",
}
```

I made these changes in the Commerce Authoring JSON file. And then I am rebuilding the indexes with the help of Postman by Running the full index Minion for each of them.

But still, I am not able to enable SwitchOnRebuild.

I also have a doubt that did we need to do it for the Commerce Default indexes while working with SolrCloud.

If No then why it's not working.
If Yes then how I can achieve that.

Also, I have not created any alias in SolrCloud.
I don't know what things or what collections, I need to create manually in SolrCloud.

Any Help would be great!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SwitchOnRebuild feature was released with XC 9.3 and should be enabled OOTB https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Commerce/93/Sitecore%20Experience%20Commerce%2093%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes
What is your XC version?

Comment: I am using Sitecore XC 9.0.3

Comment: You need to upgrade to XC 9.3 or create a ticket for Sitecore Support. Might be they have any hotfix, which makes SwitchOnRebuild possible on XC 9.0.3

Comment: Thanks @AndreiPaliakou for the information.

Comment: If you have the ZK setup, you don't need any SwitchOnRebuild or alias, that's the beauty of having solr with ZK, I'm not sure what you have configured for shards and replica, but whenever you do a full index on the main collection ZK will create a temp collection internally and swap that collection with the main collection.

Comment: I had ZK installed but it's not creating any temp collection while doing a full index with the help of Postman.